# Earth Engine - function for printing multiple histograms

Tags: google-earth-engine, function, histogram

I have several time periods within a feature where the precipitation was very low stored in a FeatureCollection with the properties "begin", "end", "amount", "days".I want to use the feature properties begin and end to filter the Sentinel-1 GRD Collection for creating several Histograms at the same time. is this possible with a function and than map()?
[link to gee script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c23348a9b25609fd863c82b4c5c12fb1)

I start but i don't know how to do it with the histograms...

Here my function snippet

```
function hist(feature) {
  //Get properties of feature for filtering Sentinel-1 ImageCollection 
  var begin = feature.get("begin")
  var end = feature.get("end")
  var days = feature.get("days")
  var amount = feature.get("amount")
  return ui.Chart.image.histogram(s1_collection.filterDate(begin,end,30))
  }
```

By the way is there any filter to get an image or feature by their row number?

Comment: Please as only one question per Question.

Comment: You should give access to your asset folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the charting functions inside a server-side map().  The charts are all in the browser, so the server doesn't know anything about them.  You could compute the histograms this way using reduceRegion and a histogram reducer, but you wont be able to chart them.